# Generating docx document from PHP ms sql html table

Tags: php, sql-server, docx

I have a table that I would like to export as a docx document, anyone could suggest a way to do so,

I have attached an image of the website on the left and on the right is the document I want to output those into the docx.

Thanks

Comment: you can create html and open it with word or print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHPDOCx at https://www.phpdocx.com/. Sample code:

```
require_once 'pathToPHPDocX/classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();

$html='<p>This is a simple paragraph with <strong>text in bold</strong>.</p>
<p>Now we include a list:</p>
<ul>
    <li>First item.</li>
    <li>Second item with subitems:
        <ul>
            <li>First subitem.</li>
            <li>Second subitem.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Third subitem.</li>
</ul>
<p>And now a table:</p>
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>Cell 1 1</td>
        <td>Cell 1 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 2 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>';

$docx->embedHTML($html);

$docx->createDocx('simpleHTML');
```

If you want an external page to be converted into html, add the contents using file_get_contents functions in a variable and send it to embedHTML